# Using records for classes that only contain logic

Tags: c#, record

Since the introduction of C# records I've started using them in cases where all of my class members are immutable, even if the purpose of the class is not to encapsulate data, for example in a DAL:

```
public record MyDataAccess(DatabaseConnectionFactory Db)
{
    public int GetValue()
    {
        using var conn = Db.Connect();
        return conn.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT Foo FROM Bar");
    }
    // Other members here
}
```

From what I have read this is not the intended use case of records, however I can't see any problems with this and I've also not read anything indicating that this pattern is to be avoided.

Am I okay to continue to use records in cases like this, or is this pattern going to cause issues in some way that I'm not seeing?

Comment: For me records are just another tool in the toolbox. I do not see anything objectionable in your specific example. I think the important thing is to agree on a coding convention *in your team* to minimize surprises.

Comment: That seems like a perfectly acceptable use of `record` to me. However, I think answers to this question are going to be subjective...

Comment: After all a record is a class with some extras. When to use a class or a record might be a convinence. But if the question is about "Is it OK" my answer would be yes it compiles fine. I personally use records when i need the out of the box equality for example.